# populating fields on a page on startup - Grails App

Tags: grails, gsp, bootstrapping

Im new to grails and now I'm stuck on something.

I've created my app and It works fine.

Now I would like to populate some fields that are on the startup page ( in my case called Report.gsp) after some queries have been performed to retrieve the values.

I have a query executing in the bootstrap at startup but i don't know how to get them to my gsp page after that to populate the field.

here's the bootstrap code:

```
    class BootStrap {
        def dataSource
        def grailsApplication

        def init = { servletContext ->
            initData()
    }

    def destroy = {
    }

    def initData(){
       println("***** in initDATA")
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

        def results
        results = sql.execute("select * from customer where id = 42;")
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails uses the MVC design pattern. To pass values to your view (`report.gsp`), you'll need to retrieve the data inside your controller, and pass it to your view. Your `Bootstrap.groovy` file is for performing actions that need to happen when your application starts up, such as seeding data, not to populate the views.

If this is your home page, you should create a new controller and action, and map your root URL to that controller action, then perform your data lookup in that controller action.

For example, create the `HomeController.groovy` in `grails-app/controllers`:

```
class HomeController {

  def index() {
    // Lookup your data
    def customer = Customer.get(params.id)

    // Pass the results to the view
    [customer: customer]
  }
}
```

You can then map your root URL to this action in `grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
"/"(controller: "home", action: "index")
```

Your view should then be created at `grails-app/controllerName/actionName.gsp`. In our case this would be `grails-app/home/index.gsp`:

```
<ul>
  <li>Customer ID: ${customer?.id}</li>
  <li>Customer Name: ${customer?.name}</li>
  <li>Customer Age: ${customer?.age}</li>
  <!-- Whatever fields you'd like to display -->
</ul>
```

Now when someone navigates to the root URL in your application, the HomeController#index action will perform the lookup, and pass the data to your view to be displayed.

Comment: Why would you use the null safe operator in `Customer.get(params?.id)` ?  The `params` property will never be null when the action is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the help, at least it executes the query but why cant i use the results = sql.execute("select name from customer where id = 42;")

Comment: @ReneChamberot You can do it that way if you'd like, it's just not really the Grails convention. Grails gives you [dynamic finders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#finders) and [where queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries) (among others) to make querying your GORM objects simpler, and to keep you from having to embed SQL into your application code.